# Issue when converting from NVARCHAR to VARBINARY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, varbinary

When converting `varchar` to `varbinary`, I can revert it back. For example:

```
SELECT CAST('_A_Brand1[_1]A5_LP[_1].A5' AS VARBINARY)
      ,CAST('_A_Brand1[_1]A5_LP[_2].A5' AS VARBINARY);
```

gives two different outputs:

> 0x5F415F4272616E64315B5F315D41355F4C505B5F3**1**5D2E4135
>   0x5F415F4272616E64315B5F315D41355F4C505B5F3**2**5D2E4135

but if I use `nvarchar` I get the same output:

```
SELECT CAST(N'_A_Brand1[_1]A5_LP[_1].A5' AS VARBINARY)
      ,CAST(N'_A_Brand1[_1]A5_LP[_2].A5' AS VARBINARY);
```

> 0x5F0041005F004200720061006E00640031005B005F0031005D0041003500
>   0x5F0041005F004200720061006E00640031005B005F0031005D0041003500

Which is an issue, because I can not perform correct operations later:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST('_A_Brand1[_1]A5_LP[_1].A5' AS VARBINARY) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
      ,CAST(CAST('_A_Brand1[_1]A5_LP[_2].A5' AS VARBINARY) AS VARCHAR(MAX));

SELECT CAST(CAST(N'_A_Brand1[_1]A5_LP[_1].A5' AS VARBINARY) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
      ,CAST(CAST(N'_A_Brand1[_1]A5_LP[_2].A5' AS VARBINARY) AS NVARCHAR(MAX));
```

The first is OK:

```
_A_Brand1[_1]A5_LP[_1].A5
_A_Brand1[_1]A5_LP[_2].A5
```

The second returns same strings (value is lost/cut):

```
_A_Brand1[_1]A5
_A_Brand1[_1]A5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default length of `VARBINARY` is 30, that's why data is truncated.

Corrected code:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(N'_A_Brand1[_1]A5_LP[_1].A5' AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
      ,CAST(CAST(N'_A_Brand1[_1]A5_LP[_2].A5' AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS NVARCHAR(MAX));
```